# orderBy + repartitionByRange, partitionColumn + orderBy + repartition, or partitionColumn + repartition + sortWithinPartitions, or better?

Tags: java, apache-spark

French enterprises have a `siren` code of 9 digits to recognize them
and a `siret` deriving from it, for each of their establishments, of 14 digits.

```
+---------+-----+--------------+
|siren    |nic  |siret         |
+---------+-----+--------------+
|070100045|00015|07010004500015|
|070100078|00016|07010007800016|
|070100094|00013|07010009400013|
|070100110|00017|07010011000017|
|070100128|00019|07010012800019|
|070100136|00012|07010013600012|
```

With Spark, I need to read a csv file of 34 millions records containing them, and create partitions to make its content more usable.

But I am puzzled with the `orderBy`, `repartition`, `repartitionByRange`, and `sortWithinPartition` methods.

##### 1) orderBy + repartitionByRange

```java
etablissements = etablissements
   .orderBy("siren", "siret");
   .repartitionByRange(col("siren"));
```

takes 1m58s on my computer, and creates 159 partitions.
(number returned by `dataset.rdd().getNumPartitions()`)

##### 2) partition column + orderBy + repartition

```java
etablissements = etablissements
  .withColumn("partitionSiren", col("siren").substr(1,2))
  .orderBy("partitionSiren", "siren", "siret");
  .repartition(col("partitionSiren"));
```

takes 1m 10s and creates 55 partitions.

##### 3) partition column + repartition + sortWithinPartitions

```java
etablissements = etablissements.withColumn("partitionSiren", col("siren").substr(1,2));
   .repartition(col("partitionSiren"));
   .sortWithinPartitions(col("siren"), col("siret"));
```

takes 1m 08s and creates 55 partitions.

It seems that I should choose solution #2 or solution #3, except if there's a better manner to write my statements.

If I use solution #2 or #3, I will have to query my dataset for an establishment with a statement like:

```java
dataset.where(col("partitionSiren").equalTo(...)
  .and(col("siren").equalTo(...))
  .and(col("siret").equalTo(...))
```

To allow this query to work the most efficiently, should my `sortWithinPartitions` be:

```java
etablissements.sortWithinPartitions(col("siren"), col("siret"))
```

or

```java
etablissements.sortWithinPartitions(col("partitionSiren"), 
   col("siren"), col("siret"))`
```

Comment: *I have three questions* - As per [ask], questions should ask *one* question. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @Bohemian They were very linked together. But ok, I've chosen one of them only.